# How to extract XML using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

I have one large XML file and using Python BeautifulSoup library (sample code is below), was able to extract certain part of it. Further I would like to generate output as shown below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
file = open("Physical document path", "r",encoding='utf-8')
contents = file. Read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'xml')
titles = soup.find_all('entity-list',code='Organization')
print(titles)
```

below is the filtered output from the original XML document

```
[<entity-list code="Organization">
<entity name="Energy Xxi Gulf Coast Inc">
<property code="sym">NASDAQ-NMS.EXXI</property>
<property code="acorn">4286423188</property>
<property code="use">primary</property>
</entity>
<entity name="Tema Oil and Gas Company">
<property code="acorn">1041746798</property>
<property code="uacorn">1452918703</property>
<property code="use">mention</property>
</entity>
<entity name="Rosehill Resources Inc">
<property code="sym">NASDAQ-SMALL.ROSE</property>
<property code="acorn">5011400606</property>
<property code="use">mention</property>
</entity>
<entity name="Energy Xxi (Bermuda) Limited">
<property code="acorn">0925670741</property>
<property code="use">primary</property>
</entity>
<entity name="Epl Oil &amp; Gas Inc.">
<property code="acorn">3058472513</property>
<property code="uacorn">4286423188</property>
<property code="use">mention</property>
</entity>
<entity name="Patterson-UTI Energy Inc.">
<property code="sym">NASDAQ-NMS.PTEN</property>
<property code="acorn">3673909660</property>
<property code="use">mention</property>
</entity>
<entity name="University of Illinois">
<property code="acorn">4117851479</property>
<property code="use">mention</property>
</entity>
<entity name="Tulane University">
<property code="acorn">1572344836</property>
<property code="use">mention</property>
</entity>
<entity name="Morgan Stanley &amp; Co. LLC">
<property code="acorn">0308068010</property>
<property code="uacorn">3605295726</property>
<property code="use">mention</property>
</entity>
<entity name="Morgan Stanley">
<property code="sym">NYSE.APF</property>
<property code="acorn">3605295726</property>
<property code="use">parent</property>
</entity>
</entity-list>]
```

**Below is the output I want to generate further for all the entity (sample is for first three entity) with their property code**

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add a **short, representative** sample of the original XML instead of the "filtered output".

Comment: you may consider filtered output as Original XML file in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with xml, you are probably better off using xpath and loading the whole thing to a dataframe.

So I would suggest this:
i

```
mport pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse("yourfile.xml")

#create a list of code values:
attribs = ['sym','acorn','use','uacorn']
#create a list of columns
cols = ["organization"]+attribs
#start collecting the information
rows = []
#for entity in doc.xpath('//entity'):
#EDIT - the command above should be changed to:
for entity in doc.xpath('//entity-list[@code="Organization"]//entity[@name]'):
    org = entity.xpath('./@name')[0]
    #this is a little complex because it has to account for possible missing code values
    #it uses a condition list comprehension
    codes = [entity.xpath(f'.//property[@code[.="{attrib}"]]/text()')[0] if entity.xpath(f'.//property/@code[.="{attrib}"]') else "na" for attrib in attribs ]
    rows.append([org,*codes])

#finaly, create your dataframe    
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=cols)
```

Output (based on your xml above; pardon the formatting):

```
    organization                sym                 acorn       use     uacorn
0   Energy Xxi Gulf Coast Inc   NASDAQ-NMS.EXXI     4286423188  primary     na
1   Tema Oil and Gas Company    na  1041746798  mention     1452918703
2   Rosehill Resources Inc  NASDAQ-SMALL.ROSE   5011400606  mention     na
3   Energy Xxi (Bermuda) Limited    na  0925670741  primary     na
4   Epl Oil & Gas Inc.  na  3058472513  mention     4286423188
5   Patterson-UTI Energy Inc.   NASDAQ-NMS.PTEN     3673909660  mention     na
6   University of Illinois  na  4117851479  mention     na
7   Tulane University   na  1572344836  mention     na
8   Morgan Stanley & Co. LLC    na  0308068010  mention     3605295726
9   Morgan Stanley  NYSE.APF    3605295726  parent  na
```

Comment: Since you suggest different approach from beautifulsoup to xPath. Now i am having difficulty to narrow down the original xml file to filtered output that i have mentioned above. I am sharing the original XML file here (https://file.io/YskZ1gFtsIGD), can you help to revise the code accordingly?

Comment: This is perfect. I appreciate your quick help on this.

Comment: Yes, I already accepted the answer